# How can I get the name of my vectors from my function into the legend?

Tags: r, plot

```
compareECDFs<-function(x,i,xlab){
    ecdf1<-ecdf(c(x))
    ecdf2<-ecdf(c(i))
    xlab<-xlab
    name<-c(c(x),c(i))
plot1<-plot(ecdf1,ylab="Cumulative relative frequency",xlab=xlab,lty=ifelse(c(x)>c(i),"solid","dotted"),verticals=TRUE,xlim=range(c(x),c(i)))
lines1<-lines(ecdf2,lty=ifelse(c(i)>c(x),"solid","dotted"),verticals=TRUE)
legend1<-legend("right",legend=c(print(name)),lty=c(1,3),cex=0.8)
output<-c(plot1,lines1,legend1)
return(output)
}
```

I am trying to get my legend to return the name of my vectors so when I call my function it shows their names in the legend.
ex.

```
> compareECDFs(vec1,vec2,"dbh")
```

legend labels will be vec1 and vec2

Comment: something like `legend=c(deparse(substitute(x)))` ?

Comment: is there a way to make that work for both x and i in the function?

Comment: I got it by using legend=c(deparse(substitute(x)),deparse(substitute(i))) thank you!